# Regular Expression match any literal values between two variable strings

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am fresh to regular expression

I would like to use regular expression (`REGEXP_LIKE`) to search a Oracle DB table column whose value is between 2 variable strings with format `"ANNNN" or "ANNNNA"`, e.g.

```
[A1000 - Z9999] returns 'A1111', 'B1234', 'T5678', etc.

[B1234S - C8888S] returns 'B1234S', 'B1235S', 'C88888S', etc.

[A1000S - D9999] returns 'A1000S', 'A1001', 'A1001S', etc.
```

How could I do it?

Thank you

Comment: While it may be possible to do this, the regular expressions will be extremely complex. Why not just do numeric comparisons of the substrings?

Comment: It seems impossible. the UI allows users to enter the range "from" and "to" which accept exact values or wildcards (e.g. %, A%, A%S, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regex for everything. Use it to check if the format is right and then convert to a number to check the value.

Your first example:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(your_column, '^[A-Z]\d{4}$')
  AND TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(your_column, '\D')) BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999;
```

Your second example:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(your_column, '^[BC]\d{4}S$')
  AND TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(your_column, '\D')) BETWEEN 1234 AND 8888;
```

Your third example:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(your_column, '^[A-Z]\d{4}S?$')
  AND TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE(your_column, '\D')) BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999;
```

---

If your UI only allows users to enter the format you've specified, you have to convert those to conditions. You can't expect the users to enter complex regexes, so you will have to do *some* conversion anyway.

You may be able to get away with just using the bare values your user enter. For the first example, I think a simple `BETWEEN` would work.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_column BETWEEN min_value AND max_value;
```

For the other examples, *if you can make assumptions about the format of the strings your users will enter*, you can convert those to conditions.

For instance, if you know that the format of those strings will be `[A-Z][0-9]{4}S?` (a letter, followed by four digits, followed by an optional S), you can analyse the strings and build a regex from them.
For your second example, that would mean matching the first letter of both and making a character class out of them, matching the digits of both and using them as the lower and upper bounds for your `BETWEEN` and matching the optional S — if both strings have it, it's mandatory, if neither string has it, it's not allowed, and if only one has an S, it's optional.

Comment: Dear guru, many thanks. But, as told, uses would enter something like 'A1000', 'A%', '%S', etc. in 'from' and 'to' input fields which are not predictable (may not be like the examples). So, are there any more "generic" SQL to handle all the possible cases?